# Finding the nth value of Recamán's Sequence

Tags: java

One of my lab questions is to write a piece of code that calculates the nth value of Recamán's Sequence.

The test cases I'm given go up to the 100,000th value of Recamán's sequence and the algorithm for determining the value itself isn't my issue, my issue is writing the program in a way that it doesn't take too long to run. to accomplish this my prof has given us the hint to use a sufficiently large Boolean[] of size n*10 and use it to keep track of which integer values are already part of the generated sequence, instead of iterating through the entire previously generated values.

I have code that I believe should do this just fine but the issue I'm running out of array indicies. Looking through the auto tester we are supplied with, it randomly asks for the nth value from 1-100,000. However around I run into the issue of running out of space in my Boolean[] to check if the number has been generated.

My code is the following

```
   public static int recaman(int n){
        int[] seq = new int[n];
        boolean[] check = new boolean[10 * n]; 

        seq[0]=0;
        check[0]=true;
        for(int k=1;k<=n;k++){
            int minusVal = seq[k-1]-k;
            int plusVal = seq[k-1] + k;
            if((minusVal>0)&&(!check[seq[minusVal]])){
                seq[k]= minusVal;
                check[minusVal] = true;
            }else{
                seq[k] = plusVal;
                check[plusVal]=true;
            }
        }
        return seq[n];
   }
```

and running recaman(100) results in the following error

> Java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 104
>   at
>   P2J2.recaman(P2J2.java:78)

What's weird is that the error doesn't appear every time for small numbers but happens almost all the time for any number above ~400.

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong, if someone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

!check[minusVal] is the correct way.

```
public static int recaman(int n)
        {
            int[] seq = new int[n];
            boolean[] check = new boolean[10 * n];

            seq[0] = 0;
            check[0] = true;
            for (int k = 1; k < n; k++)
            {
                int minusVal = seq[k - 1] - k;
                int plusVal = seq[k - 1] + k;
                if ((minusVal > 0) && (!check[minusVal]))
                {
                    seq[k] = minusVal;
                    check[minusVal] = true;
                } else
                {
                    seq[k] = plusVal;
                    check[plusVal] = true;
                }
            }
            return seq[n - 1];
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

For `k=16` `minusVal = 104` and you check `!check[seq[minusVal]]`. This is the reason for error. Seems like you need to make `int[] seq = new int[n * 10];` too. Hope it helps!

PS. I tested it with `int[] seq = new int[n * 10];` and still have the same error. In general, the condition `!check[seq[minusVal]]` is wrong and can lead to wrong results. You should replace it with `!check[minusVal]` because you want to check if `MinusVal` was present before, not `seq[minusVal]`.

This code works without errors for me:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static int recaman(int n){
        int[] seq = new int[n * 10];
        boolean[] check = new boolean[10 * n]; 

        seq[0]=0;
        check[0]=true;
        for(int k=1;k<=n;k++){
            int minusVal = seq[k-1]-k;
            int plusVal = seq[k-1] + k;
            if((minusVal>0)&&(!check[minusVal])){
                seq[k]= minusVal;
                check[minusVal] = true;
            }else{
                seq[k] = plusVal;
                check[plusVal]=true;
            }
        }
        return seq[n];
   }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        recaman(100000);
    }
}
```

Comment: After making the change the new error I seem to be running into is check[plusVal]=true; where plusVal is equal to a higher index then what check goes to. Trying to up the size of the two arrays doesn't seem like it's fixing the problem. Thank you for your input however.

Comment: Right you are! I Edited my answer, seems like the bug was right in this place)